# Get a line number where Write-Error occurred

Tags: powershell

Consider the script

```
$someComplexCondition = $false

if ($someComplexCondition)
{
    Write-Error -Message "Some complex condition"
}
else
{
    Write-Error -Message "Other complex condition"
}
```

When I run it it says

```
C:\Dev> .\MyScript.ps1
C:\Dev\MyScript.ps1 : Other complex condition
At line:1 char:15
+ .\MyScript.ps1 <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,MyScript.ps1
```

And I noticed that **Write-Error** always reports itself as **at line:1**
According to the stack trace it looks like it's line #1 because it was called from the shell and more interesting **char:15** because

```
".\MyScript.ps1 ".Length -eq 15
```

If we change file name, this **char:15** will be changed accordingly.

The question is how to get the actual line when the error occurred.

In our case I would like to get **line:9**

Answer (score 1):

When there is an actual error, generated by Powershell you get an object of the type ErrorRecord :

```
$error[0] | Get-Member

    TypeName: System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord
```

When you use this same ErrorRecord with Write-Error, you don't get an object :

```
$myError = Write-Error -ErrorRecord $Error[0]
PS C:\> $MyError | Get-Member
gm : You must specify an object for the Get-Member cmdlet.
At line:1 char:12
+ $MyError | gm
+            ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-Member], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoObjectInGetMember,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetMemberCommand
```

So now, we know that Write-Error will not give us anything that we can reuse later.

You can use the "Throw" statement, instead :

```
$someComplexCondition = $false

if ($someComplexCondition)
{
    Throw "Some complex condition"
}
else
{
    Throw "Other complex condition"
}
```

Then, when you run the script, the error gives you the line number and character number of the start of the "Throw" statement :

```
C:\Test-Error.ps1
Other complex condition
At C:\Test-Error.ps1:9 char:5
+     Throw "Other complex condition"
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Other complex condition:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Other complex condition
```

Here, it is line number 9.

Comment: I am using **throw** in my own scripts. The reason for my question is when you use something 3rd-party which is using **Write-Error**. And when it fails it is better to be able to quickly identify the exact place

Comment: There are a few ways to correct that by modifying MyScript.ps1. The problem comes from the fact that this script is using Write-Error. If you cannot modify MyScript.ps1, there is no efficient way to solve this.

Comment: Too bad... That's the only thing missing for my boilerplate scripts headings to improve scripting experience

Comment: This is really sad if Write-Error can't be helped. Is it still true even if you've got things like $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop" in your script? That gives me sanity with things like using unset variables, but tracking *where* the unset variable is used is a chore when I get line 1 char 1 everytime...